# How to get a text from HTML using span ID in VB.NET (Visual Basic 2010)?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

How do I get a string from an HTML document using span ID in VB.NET (Visual Basic 2010)?

I am working on a project, and I wanted to extract text from a webpage span to my application's `textbox1.text`. I only used this so far:

```
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("***I put the span id here, but it didn't work.***")(0).InnerText
```

Comment: lets say i want to count people who viewed my videos on YouTube since that is a span then i want to convert that to a text box in my application...i already know how to get text by just element ids 

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `...ByName` and not `...ByID` which mean you need to use the `name` attribute of the `span` element:

```
<span name="myName">...</span>
```

To use ID instead of name try replacing your code to (untested):

```
TextBox1.Text = _
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("spanID").GetAttribute("innerText")
```

...

```
<span id="spanID">...</span>
```

Comment: i replaced the span id with the span id name...still doesnt work

Comment: here what is the webbrowser1?

Comment: @user3262364 that is a web browser control, WebBrowser1 is usually the default name for the first instance (ref. OP's post).

Comment: I am trying the above example and I'm getting the following error: _'Cannot get inner content of searchBoxValues because the contents are not literal.'_
Any ideas on that?